# VS Code: How to find all references of a variable in python?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, pycharm

I'd like a VS Code feature like [**Find Usages**](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/finding-usages-in-project.html) in Pycharm, which can find all reads and writes of a variable. Take a simple file for example:

```
class Foo:
    def __init__(self, bar):
        self.bar = bar

    def do_something(self):
        bar1 = "hhhhh"
        if bar1 == self.bar:
            print("do something")
```

In Pycharm using "Find Usages" of `self.bar`:

[image: Find Usages screenshot]

I've tried "Find all references" but it doesn't work:

[image: Find all references screenshot]

as it doesn't find `if bar1 == self.bar:`.

**Update**: searching for just occurrences is not what I am asking, as it just matches keywords which includes other variables with same name and also occurrences in comments.

**Update**: turns out to be a known issue in Microsoft python language server: [github.com/microsoft/python-language-server/issues/1174](http://github.com/microsoft/python-language-server/issues/1174)

Comment: Do you want to find occurrences across multiple files or just the one currently open in the editor?

Comment: @ipconfig across multiple files

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot reproduce this in my VSCode... https://imgur.com/a/H1TWxqT

Comment: I can't reproduce either, with the same result as ifconfig. Maybe your vscode version is old? https://imgur.com/Z4GWU57

Comment: I'm using the latest vscode... maybe because of some extension configurations?

Comment: @monotasker maybe? I'm using https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-python.python as my only Python extension.

Comment: @AdamSmith I might find the cause, you can try my answer to reproduce it...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem occurs with my user setting of python extension `jediEnabled` option as false:

```
"python.jediEnabled": false,
```

so switch back to the default:

```
// Enables Jedi as IntelliSense engine instead of Microsoft Python Analysis Engine.
  "python.jediEnabled": true,
```

and "Find all references" works in the example!

Maybe it's a bug in Microsoft Python Analysis Engine.

Comment: If this didn't work with the language server would you mind filing a bug at https://github.com/microsoft/python-language-server?

Comment: @BrettCannon I found this issue https://github.com/microsoft/python-language-server/issues/1174. Also https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/5260. It seems there are many issues about this yet no solution...

Comment: I have *jedi* enabled by default and added `/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/` as the "Jedi Path", but still "Find all references" does not show, for example, where a function is called.

Comment: @Nagev yeah function calls don't really work well on my machine either.

Comment: If I have jedi disabled, `find all references` only works for  non-class functions, non class members` They gave 0 results. Module-level seem to work. Otherwise I toggle `Jedi` to on, and now all functions find references as expected. I wonder if it has to do with having `Visual Studio IntelliCode` enabled. (Note: this is not a typo, there's `intellicode` (addon) and `intellisense` (default)) -- @monotasker do you happen to be using intellicode for python too?

Answer (score 5):

The "Find All References" feature works well in VS Code when using the pylance language service from Microsoft (new in July 2020) https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-python.vscode-pylance

Right+click on a symbol then select "Find All References" from the context menu.  This worked well, even finding methods referenced in different modules within a workspace.

Answer (score -2):

**Find Usages. Variable Options**

*Edit | Find | Find Usages*
**Alt+F7**
This section describes **Field, Variable, or Parameter usage search options** in the Find Usages dialog.

The dialog opens when you click icons general settings svg in the Show Usages popup which lists all the occurrences of the symbol at caret.

Source: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/find-usages-variable-options.html

Comment: Thanks. The question is about how to enable this feature in Visual Studio Code. We know it works in PyCharm.

Answer (score -4):

In VS Code use ctrl+shift+f and type what you want to search, it will show all the occurences of your typed word in the path / in project level.

Comment: Oh sorry, honest mistake. Early morning here. I have edited my answer.

Comment: You are essentially talking about searching but not what I am asking, because searching just matches keywords so it includes other variables with same name and also occurrences in comments.